# Cypress failing when using a Proxy

Tags: proxy, cypress

Our product security team developed a proxy tool that our tests can use such that the traffic from our app can be captured and analyzed for vulnerabilities.  In general, the proxy is working well. I can manually use our application and the traffic is recorded However, when I set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY OS environment variables to use the proxy, Cypress 'fails'.  If I try to run tests, they never really start.  Just executing "Cypress Open" fails.  In that case, the Cypress window opens but it never displays the available tests, etc.  The cursor just spins continuously.
I enabled debugging when running "Cypress open". When capturing cypress:network:agent logging, this is what is logged - note the last line:

```
  cypress:network:agent addRequest called { isHttps: true, href: 'https://download.cypress.io/desktop.json' } +0ms
  cypress:network:agent got family { family: undefined, href: 'https://download.cypress.io/desktop.json' } +4ms
  cypress:network:agent Creating proxied socket for https://download.cypress.io/desktop.json through https://ourproxy.ourlocation.com:8010 +3ms
  cypress:network:client-certificates loaded client certificates for 0 URL(s) +0ms
  cypress:network:agent addRequest called { isHttps: true, href: 'https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' } +2s
  cypress:network:agent got family { family: 4, href: 'https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' } +0ms
  cypress:network:agent Creating proxied socket for https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ through https://ourproxy.ourlocation.com:8010 +1ms
```

If I log everything, the only statements logged after the "Creating proxied socket...." statement is some repeated profiling data.
I'm looking for thoughts on whether this might be a cypress problem/bug or an issue with the proxy tool.
I've googled for similar issues and tried many of the suggested solutions/workarounds to no avail.
Ideas appreciated.  Thank you.

I tried various flavors of NO_PROXY settings.  I tried using the electron browser rather then chrome.